# How to combine 2 rows in pandas DataFrame with consecutive timestamp?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe like given below

```
start_time                     end_time   value                                
2017-01-09 21:49:55 2017-01-09 21:55:41  150.0
2017-01-09 21:55:41 2017-01-09 21:58:46    4.0
2017-01-09 22:00:55 2017-01-09 23:13:00  144.0
```

I want

```
start_time                     end_time   value                                
2017-01-09 21:49:55 2017-01-09 21:58:46  154.0
2017-01-09 22:00:55 2017-01-09 23:13:00  144.0
```

As first 2 rows were consecutive events, I joined it into a single row and added their values.
Any suggestions how can i proceed.

Comment: Consecutive based on what?

Comment: 2 rows are consecutive if first row's end_time is same as second row's start_time.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your dataframe is already sorted by time

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

'''
start_time                     end_time   value                                
2017-01-09 21:49:55 2017-01-09 21:55:41  150.0
2017-01-09 21:55:41 2017-01-09 21:58:46    4.0
2017-01-09 22:00:55 2017-01-09 23:13:00  144.0
'''

# your dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({'start_time': [datetime(2017,1,9,21,49,55), datetime(2017,1,9,21,55,41),datetime(2017,1,9,22,00,55)], \
                    'end_time': [datetime(2017,1,9,21,55,41), datetime(2017,1,9,21,58,46),datetime(2017,1,9,23,13,00)], \
                    'value': [150.0, 4.0, 144.0]})
```

get the first `start_time` of a consecutive time range, and the latest `end_time` of a consecutive time range:

```
df['start_time_'] = df['start_time'].loc[df['end_time'].shift(1) != df['start_time']]
df['end_time_'] = df['end_time'].loc[df['end_time'] != df['start_time'].shift(-1)]

print(df)
```

now `df` looks like below:

```
  start_time          end_time             value start_time_         end_time_
0 2017-01-09 21:49:55 2017-01-09 21:55:41  150.0 2017-01-09 21:49:55                 NaT
1 2017-01-09 21:55:41 2017-01-09 21:58:46    4.0                 NaT 2017-01-09 21:58:46
2 2017-01-09 22:00:55 2017-01-09 23:13:00  144.0 2017-01-09 22:00:55 2017-01-09 23:13:00
```

then fill the NA value:

```
df['start_time_'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
df['end_time_'].fillna(method='bfill',inplace=True)
```

use `start_time_`, `end_time_` columns to replace `start_time`, `end_time` columns. And delete `start_time_`, `end_time_` columns:

```
df['start_time'] = df['start_time_']
df['end_time'] = df['end_time_']
del df['start_time_'] 
del df['end_time_']
```

then groupby and sum:

```
df = df.groupby(['start_time', 'end_time'], as_index=False).sum()

print(df)
```

the result is as below:

```
           start_time            end_time  value
0 2017-01-09 21:49:55 2017-01-09 21:58:46  154.0
1 2017-01-09 22:00:55 2017-01-09 23:13:00  144.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant way but it kinda works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"start":[1,2,4], "end":[2,3,5], 'val':[1,1,1]})
tmp = df.set_index('end', drop=0).join(df.set_index('start', drop=0), how='left', rsuffix='_r')
tmp.val = tmp.val_r.fillna(0) + tmp.val
df = tmp[~tmp.end.isin(tmp.end_r)][['start', 'end', 'val']]
df.index = range(len(df))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Jan.
Here df is 
   end  start  val
0    2      1    1
1    3      2    1
2    5      4    1
This is giving output as : 
   start  end  val
0      1    2  2.0
1      4    5  1.0

I expect the output to be 
   start  end  val
0      1    3  2.0
1      4    5  1.0

Difference is in the end value.